# Tracing UNIX signal origins?

Tags: linux, signals, unix

If I have a process that receives signals from other processes, is there a way for me to somehow tell which process (if any) sent a signal?

`strace` lets me trace which signals a process has received, but doesn't allow me to trace who issued them.

Comment: As far as I can see, the current solutions do not allow me to find out which process killed/stopped another process if SIGKILL or SIGSTOP was used. True?

Comment: you have to look at dynamic tracing methods for such voodoo, like bpftrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ptrace` can be used to detect sender too. There is an `ptrace(GETSIGINFO)` call, which will give a debugger a chance to read (and, possibly, change) `siginto_t` struct.

Answer (score 10):

For Linux users, there is a very easy way to identify the source of a signal. For example, the following is to find which task sends SIGKILL to others.

```
cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
echo 'sig==9' > events/signal/signal_generate/filter 
echo 1 > events/signal/signal_generate/enable
: > trace
echo 1 > tracing_on
tail -f trace
```

One instance, when I used 'pkill -9 sleep'.

```
# cat trace
[...]
       pkill-2982  [001] d... 750347.835838: signal_generate: sig=9 errno=0 code=0 comm=sleep pid=2981 grp=1 res=0
```

Without above 'sig==9' filter, 'trace' will show all signals sent among tasks.

Answer (score 9):

Not from outside the process. The second argument to the signal handler is a `siginfo_t` structure which contains the PID of the sending process as one of its members. See [`sigaction(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) for more details.